# What is Floer homology of a knot?

Tags: knot-theory, floer-homology, gn.general-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

I've heard that there are different theories providing knot invariants in form of homologies.  My understanding is that if you embed knot in a special way into a space, there is a special homology theory called Floer homology.

> **Question:** what's the definition and properties of a Floer homology of a knot? How is it related to other knot homology theories?

Comment: There is a really long Wikipedia article on Floer homology.  Could you ask a more specific question?

Comment: Sorry, what is the article you're referring to? The one I found, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floer_homology, doesn't seem to answer my question about "what's ... Floer homology **of a knot**"

Comment: I think this part of that wiki article answers your question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floer_homology#Floer_homology_of_three-manifolds (or maybe I don't understand your question..)

Comment: The wiki article says that there is a knot invariant coming from a filtration on the Heegaard Floer homology of a 3-manifold, but nothing about what that filtration is or what properties the associated object has (other than categorifying the Alexander polynomial).  My long answer below was an attempt to explain some of that.

Comment: Let's not have too too many of these "What is X?" questions.

Comment: @David, indeed, the wiki article contains just a short paragraph overview of a very big topic, and following the links there doesn't help me to understand what happens.

Comment: @Scott, o...k, it could be possible to follow  your advice, but could you provide more reasoning about it first? I don't know if the meta discussion should be posted on on meta.mathexchange.net rather then here though.

Comment: @Ilya: the consensus on meta.MO is that you should not treat MO as an encyclopedia. It wastes the time of whoever is polite enough to answer the question because it doesn't give them any idea where you're coming from; the only option is to write an article. Please ask questions about things that *you are seriously thinking about* rather than just shooting off vague questions asking people to explain something you came across once. If you're thinking about something philosophical, you should still be able to ask a question that has an answer. You're welcome to join the discussion on meta.

Comment: I don't know about the culture of nLab (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage), but maybe it's appropriate to request somebody write an article there. Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: I believe this whole discussion should have been on Meta, so I'm moving my comments there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can say something about this for Heegaard Floer homology.  Given a 3-manifold Y, you can take a Heegaard splitting, i.e. a decomposition of Y into two genus g handlebodies joined along their boundary.  This can be represented by drawing g disjoint curves a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>g</sub> and g disjoint curves b<sub>1</sub>,...,b<sub>g</sub> on a surface S of genus g; then you attach 1-handles along the a<sub>i</sub> and 2-handles along the b<sub>i</sub>, and fill in what's left of the boundary with 0-handles and 3-handles to get Y.

The products T<sub>a</sub>=a<sub>1</sub>x...xa<sub>g</sub> and T<sub>b</sub>=b<sub>1</sub>x...xb<sub>g</sub> are Lagrangian tori in the symmetric product Sym<sup>g</sup>(S), which has a complex structure induced from S, and applying typical constructions from Lagrangian Floer homology gives you a chain complex CF(Y) whose generators are points in the intersection of these tori and whose differential counts certain holomorphic disks in Sym<sup>g</sup>(S).  Miraculously, its homology HF(Y) turns out to be independent of every choice you made along the way.  We can also pick a basepoint z in the surface S and identify a hypersurface {z}xSym<sup>g-1</sup>(S) in Sym<sup>g</sup>(S), and we can count the number n<sub>z</sub>(u) of times these disks cross that hypersurface: if we only count disks where n<sub>z</sub>(u)=0, for example, we get the hat version of HF, and otherwise we get more complicated versions.

Given two points z and w on the surface S of any Heegaard splitting we can construct a knot in Y: draw one curve in S-{a<sub>i</sub>} and another in S-{b<sub>i</sub>} connecting z and w, and push these slightly into the corresponding handlebodies.  In fact, for any knot K in Y there is a Heegaard splitting such that we can construct K in this fashion.  But now this extra basepoint w gives a filtration on CF(Y); in the simplest form, if we only count holomorphic disks u with n<sub>z</sub>(u)=n<sub>w</sub>(u)=0 we get the invariant $\widehat{HFK}(Y,K)$, and otherwise we get other versions.  The fact that this comes from a filtration also gives us a spectral sequence HFK(Y,K) => HF(Y).

This was constructed independently by Ozsvath-Szabo and Rasmussen, and it satisfies several interesting properties.  Just to name a few:

- for knots K in S<sup>3</sup> it has a bigrading (a,m), and the Euler characteristic $\sum_m (-1)^m HFK_m(S^3,K,a)$ is the Alexander polynomial  of K;
- there's a skein exact sequence relating HFK for K and various resolutions at a fixed crossing;
- the filtered chain homotopy type of CFK tells you about the Heegaard Floer homology of various surgeries on K;
- the highest a for which HFK<sub>*</sub>(S<sup>3</sup>,K,a) is nonzero is the Seifert genus of the knot;
- If Y-K is irreducible and K is nullhomologous, then HFK(Y,K,g(K)) = Z if and only if K is fibered (proved by Ghiggini for genus 1 and Ni in general, and later by Juhasz as well).

For knots in S<sup>3</sup> it is also known how to compute HFK(K) combinatorially: see papers by Manolescu-Ozsvath-Sarkar and Manolescu-Ozsvath-Szabo-Thurston.

The relation to other knot homology theories isn't all that well understood, but there are some results comparing it to Khovanov homology.  For example, given a knot K in S<sup>3</sup>:

- Just as Lee's spectral sequence for Khovanov homology gave a concordance invariant s(K), the spectral sequence from HFK(K) to HF(S<sup>3</sup>) gives a concordance invariant tau(K), and both of these provide lower bounds on the slice genus of K.  (Hedden and Ording showed that these invariants are not equal.)
- There's a spectral sequence from the Khovanov homology of the mirror of K to HF of the branched double cover of K.
- For quasi-alternating knots, both Khovanov homology and HFK are determined entirely by the Jones and Alexander polynomials, respectively, as well as the signature; this can be proven using skein exact sequences for both (Manolescu-Ozsvath).

Anyway, that was long enough that I've probably made several mistakes above and still not been anywhere near rigorous.  There's a nice overview that's now several years old (and thus probably missing some of the things I said above) on Zoltan Szabo's website, http://www.math.princeton.edu/~szabo/clay.pdf, if you want more details.